# Regex to get the tags

Tags: c#, html, regex, vb.net

I have a html like this :

```
<h1> Headhing </h>
<font name="arial">some text</font></br>
some other text
```

In C#, 
I want to get the out put as below. Simply content inside the font start tag and end tag

```
<font name="arial">some text</font>
```

Comment: And if there is a `<font>` tag inside a `<font>` tag?

Comment: Obligatory: *You can't parse [X]HTML with regex.* ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: This has been answered 100times in SO. Regex is NOT the best way to parse HTML. As PeeHaa said use HTMl Agility pack.

Comment: assume this is not html and some other string. Then what will be the solution?. its about RegEx syntax and not about the content we parse. Assume it is translation program which needs tokenize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Regex regExfont = new Regex(@"<font name=""arial""[^>]*>.*</font>");
 MatchCollection rows = regExfont.Matches(string);
```

good website is http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

Comment: How to get all H* (h1, h2 h3.. 6) is the following html Please : <h1 style="some"> Some Text </h1>  <h2 style="some"> Some Text </h2>

Comment: How to get all H* (h1, h2 h3.. 6) is the following html Please : <h1 style="some"> Some Text </h1>  <h2 style="some"> Some Text </h2>

Comment: Hi Blidy, its not allowing me to increase the vote. says some message that i require 15 reputation.

Comment: relace font with <h\d remove the name=""arial"" do the same for the closing tag.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend to try it with regex.

I use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) to parse HTML and get what I want.
It's a lovely HTML parser that is commonly recommended for this. It will take malformed HTML and massage it into XHTML and then a traversable DOM, like the XML classes. So, is very useful for the code you find in the wild.

There's also an HTML parser from Microsoft MSHTML but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 4):

First off, your html is wrong.  you should close a `<h1>` with a `</h1>` not `</h>`.  This one thing is why reg ex is inappropriate to parse tags.

Second, there are hundreds of questions on SO talking about parsing html with regex.  The answer is don't.  Use something like the html agility pack.